# AccessibilityService change EditText from AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, accessibilityservice

I've created an AccessibilityService in Android where I want to display an AlertDialog after focusing on an EditText on the page (Note: The EditText could be from another app, like a login screen, so I won't always know the ID).  When you click on a 'confirm' button within the AlertDialog it populates that EditText with text.

I have all of the steps complete except for the last part...I cannot figure out how to populate the EditText with text.  I'm guessing there is a way to cast a findViewByID() method somewhere, but I don't know how to find the ID of the EditText (see above, the EditText could be from another app).  See code below, am I way off?  The code below always errors out telling me about a sealed instance problem (Cannot perform this action on a not sealed instance.).

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(final AccessibilityEvent event) {
    final AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();

    if ((event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED || event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED) && CLASS_NAME_EDIT_TEXT.equals(event.getClassName())) {

        AlertDialog.Builder mSuspendDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setTitle(R.string.str_have_password_question)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.str_decision_use_password, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        if (event.getSource() != null & event.getClassName().equals("android.widget.EditView")) {
                            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                            arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo
                                    .ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, "newtexttopopulateedittext");
                            event.getSource().performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.str_decision_close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert11 = mSuspendDialog.create();

        // Ensure we can show the dialog from this service.
        alert11.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alert11.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

1) When any activity starts, create a `List`(or whatever) of ID's of all the `EditText`'s on the screen.

2) While creating a list (or later on) iterate through the list again and check if a value is available for that view in your SQLite database.

3) If a value is available, use ACTION_PASTE to inject text in that EditText.

```
ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> inputViewsList = new ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>();
AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
refreshChildViewsList(rootNode);
for(AccessibilityNodeInfo mNode : inputViewsList){
    String viewId = mNode.getViewIdResourceName();
    Cursor cr = db.rawQuery(-----your database parameters----);
    if(cr.moveToFirst()){
        //this means you have a value for that ET
        ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clipData =ClipData.newPlainText("MyAppName", cr.getString(--Your column number--));
        clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
        mNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
    }
}
```

Database has to be used so that you can remember the values permanently. The ID which i'm getting above is a fully qualified ID with App package name and view ID. So, it remains unique system-wide.

Now about `refreshChildViews()` method:

```
private void refreshChildViews(AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode){
    int childCount = rootNode.getChildCount();
    for(int i=0; i<childCount ; i++){
        AccessibilityNodeInfo tmpNode = rootNode.getChildAt(i);
        int subChildCount = tmpNode.getChildCount();
        if(subChildCount==0){
            if(tmpNode.getClassName().toString().contentEquals("android.widget.EditText"){
                inputViewsList.add(tmpNode);
            }
            return;
        }
        if(subChildCount>0){
            refreshChildViews(tmpNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to clear the `inputViewsList` on `TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED` event!

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: The ACTION_PASTE action used here needs API 18 & higher. For API 21 & higher, there's another ACTION_SET_TEXT which works more efficiently.

Comment: I think whenever to paste text in edit text onAccessibilityEvent is called and loop continues checked on Marshmallow by using ClipboardManager